# How to find a point after wrapTransform?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a set of coordinates/points I found under the original image before warpPerspective, how do I get the corresponding points in the now cropped & corrected image which is perspective corrected ?

For example:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('sudoku.png')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape
pts1 = np.float32([[56,65],[368,52],[28,387],[389,390]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[0,300],[300,300]])

point = np.array([[10,10]])

M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
dst = cv.warpPerspective(img,M,(300,300))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
```

How do I get the new coordinate [10,10] in img map to the dst image ?

Comment: Apply the same transformation(s) on the coordinates. (i.e. `cv2.perspectiveTransform`)

Comment: doesn't perspectiveTransform doesn't know where to crop image ? I updated my questions to show what I want to get.

Comment: Could you, please, also attach a sample input image (or a link to where it came from)? (Oh I guess it's the one from OpenCV samples, right?)

Comment: yes, I get my image from opencv sample data. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/sudoku.png

Comment: Right. `perspectiveTransform` won't do any clipping, so you will have to post-process the transformed coordinates and discard those that fall outside the cropped area -- in your case you would keep points where `(0 <= x < 300) and (0 <= y < 300)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to perform the same transformations (mathematically) as you have done on the image. In this case it means using [`cv2.perspectiveTransform`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad327659ac03e5fd6894b90025e6900a7) (note that the input needs to have 1 row per point, 1 column, and 2 channels -- first being X, second Y cordinate).

This function will transform all the input points, it doesn't perform and cropping. You will need to post-process the transformed coordinates, and discard ones that fall outside the crop area. In your case you want to retain points where `(0 <= x < 300) and (0 <= y < 300)`.

---

**Sample code:**

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('sudoku.png')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape
pts1 = np.float32([[56,65],[368,52],[28,387],[389,390]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[0,300],[300,300]])

points = np.float32([[[10, 10]], [[116,128]], [[254,261]]])

M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
dst = cv.warpPerspective(img,M,(300,300))

# Transform the points
transformed = cv.perspectiveTransform(points, M)

# Perform the cropping -- filter out points that are outside the crop area
cropped = []
for pt in transformed:
    x, y = pt[0]
    if x >= 0 and x < dst.shape[1] and y >= 0 and y < dst.shape[0]:
        print "Valid point (%d, %d)" % (x, y)
        cropped.append([[x,y]])
    else:
        print "Out-of-bounds point (%d, %d)" % (x, y)

# Turn it back into a single numpy array
cropped = np.hstack(cropped)

# Visualize
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img)
for pt in points:
    x, y = pt[0]
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, c='red', marker='x')

plt.title('Input')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(dst)
for pt in transformed:
    x, y = pt[0]
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, c='red', marker='x')

plt.title('Output')

plt.show()
```

**Console Output:**

```
Out-of-bounds point (-53, -63)
Valid point (63, 67)
Valid point (192, 194)
```

**Visualization:**

[image: Visualization]